# homebrew can't install formula due to CC looking for not existing gcc version

Tags: gcc, homebrew

I am runnng Mac OS 10.12 with Xcode 8.0.

I tried to install the FEM-package elmer from ElmerCSC/homebrew-elmerfem.

```
$ brew install elmer --with-elmergui --HEAD --with-elmerice --verbose
```

> But building failed with:
>   ...
>   CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.6.2/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:57 (message):
>   Could not find compiler set in environment variable CC:
>   /usr/local/opt/gcc/bin/gcc-7.
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>   CMakeLists.txt:17 (PROJECT)
>   ...
>   CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
>   CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
>   -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>   ...
>   CPU: quad-core 64-bit arrandale
>   Homebrew Ruby: 2.0.0-p648
>   Clang: 8.0 build 800
>   Git: 2.8.4 => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
>   Perl: /usr/bin/perl
>   Python: /usr/local/bin/python => /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pytho$
>   Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
>   Java: 1.8.0_101
>   macOS: 10.12-x86_64
>   Xcode: 8.0
>   CLT: N/A
>   X11: 2.7.9 => /opt/X11
>   ==> ENV
>   CC: /usr/local/opt/gcc/bin/gcc-7
>   CXX: /usr/local/opt/gcc/bin/g++-7
>   OBJC: clang
>   OBJCXX: clang++
>   HOMEBREW_CC: clang
>   HOMEBREW_CXX: clang++
>   SDKROOT: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk
>   MAKEFLAGS: -j4
>   ...

[Here is the link to the full log file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/40rl7gwxnjz3zgj/elmer_log_003.txt?dl=0)

One strange thing to me is that the script looks for gcc-7 and g++-7 which don't exist.
But I have version gcc-6 and g++-6 installed in the very same place.
I checked .bashrc and .bash_profile but couldn't find an entry setting CC or GCC to version 7.

```
$ gcc --version
```

> Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
>   Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
>   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.0.0
>   Thread model: posix
>   InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

```
$ gcc-6 --version
```

> gcc-6 (Homebrew gcc 6.2.0) 6.2.0
>   Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
>   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

I set CC and CXX in my .bash_profile:

```
$ echo $CC
```

> /usr/local/bin/gcc-6

```
$ echo $CXX
```

> /usr/local/bin/g++-6

This seems not to have any effect.

gcc is pointing to the Xcode version 4.2.1

```
$ which gcc
```

> /usr/bin/gcc

Here is my PATH variable.
    $ echo $PATH

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin

Is this a formula or a cmake problem? How can I find out?

What could I do to get formula elmer installed?

I appreciate your help!
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the wrong gcc version problem I created two symlinks.

> $ ln -s /usr/local/opt/gcc/bin/gcc-6 /usr/local/opt/gcc/bin/gcc-7
>
> $ ln-s /usr/local/opt/gcc/bin/g++-6 /usr/local/opt/gcc/bin/g++-7

I did

> $ brew install elmer --HEAD --verbose

Now I get another error. stdlib.h is not found and compilation terminated.
[Link to log file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uhjku9c7fx41x7p/elmer_log_161028.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

As discussed [here](https://github.com/ElmerCSC/homebrew-elmerfem/issues/11) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/8xuhs1/how_to_compile_elmer_fem_on_macos_with_openmpi/) there are at the moment two methods for installing Elmer on macOS using HomeBrew:

**method 1:**

1. `brew tap dpo/openblas`
2. `brew install mumps`
3. `brew tap elmercsc/homebrew-elmerfem`
4. `brew edit elmer`
5. comment the `depends_on "scalapack"` line out
6. `brew install elmer --HEAD --with-elmergui`

**method 2:**

1. `brew tap brewsci/science`
2. `brew install mumps`
3. if that didn't work, download `mumps.rb` from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/udacity/CarND-MPC-Project/master/mumps.rb)
4. `brew install ./mumps.rb`
5. `brew tap elmercsc/homebrew-elmerfem`
6. `brew install elmer --HEAD --with-elmergui`

I hope it helps.